# Query to select a start and stop time

Tags: mysql

I have some data like this

```
[On]  [Time]
  1    157
  1    158
  0    159*
  1    170*
  1    171
  0    192*
  0    231
  1    294*
  1    295
 ...   ...
```

I want to select the times that have a *
so from the first 0 to the next 1

the output should look like

```
[Time1]  [Time2]
  159      170
  192      294
  ...      ...
```

Any advice would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rather tricky self-join does it - [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a026/1):

```
SELECT min(t1) t1, t2
FROM (
    SELECT s1.time t1, min(s2.time) t2
    FROM mytable s1
    JOIN mytable s2
      ON s1.on   < s2.on
     AND s1.time < s2.time
    GROUP BY s1.time
) x
GROUP BY t2
```